# How to calculate pixel from Lat, Lng on Google Maps API? C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, math

I have a custom projection for map of which Latitude and Longitude values are:

```
double MinLatitude = -32768.0;
double MaxLatitude = 32768.0;
double MinLongitude = -32768.0;
double MaxLongitude = 32768.0;
```

Forming bounds.

How can I now calculate X,Y from a Lat, Lng position?

Here's a prebuilt Mercator projection method to do that but doesn't seem to be working correctly, not returning expected coords.

```
public override GPoint FromLatLngToPixel(double lat, double lng, int zoom)
{
    GPoint ret = GPoint.Empty;

    lat = Clip(lat, MinLatitude, MaxLatitude);
    lng = Clip(lng, MinLongitude, MaxLongitude);

    double x = (lng + 180) / 360;
    double sinLatitude = Math.Sin(lat * Math.PI / 180);
    double y = 0.5 - Math.Log((1 + sinLatitude) / (1 - sinLatitude)) / (4 * Math.PI);

    GSize s = GetTileMatrixSizePixel(zoom);
    long mapSizeX = s.Width;
    long mapSizeY = s.Height;

    ret.X = (long)Clip(x * mapSizeX + 0.5, 0, mapSizeX - 1);
    ret.Y = (long)Clip(y * mapSizeY + 0.5, 0, mapSizeY - 1);

    return ret;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To me it seems that your Lat/Lng coordinates are not right. I'd say that FromLatLngToPixel method accepts lat and lng in decimal degrees or WGS84 projection (lat -> from -90 to 90, lng -> from -180 to 180), what you have is in some other projection.

Comment: Ah right, I actually just figured that, should that be a Cartesian projection instead?

Comment: I'm not sure to what your question refers. Where do you get you coordinates from? It's hard to say which projection it is, might be EPSG:3857 (together with  EPSG:4326 (or WGS84) one of the most common projections). Take a look a this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet